# How to get class name outside a class, given one of its functions

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
def print_class_name(func):
    def print_name(*args, **kw):
    print(func.__name__)            # 'whatever_func'
    print(func.__class__.__name__)  # it doesn't work :(

class Foo():
    @print_class_name
    def whatever_func(self):
        pass
```

I can only touch the decorator function `print_class_name`, but not class `Foo`. How can I print the name of the class ('Foo') using `print_class_name` decorator?

Please, note that this is a simplification. Class and decorator may be in different modules.

Answer (score 2):

If the method is not static (it requires an instance of the class), I think you can get the class that defines that method from `method_name.__self__.__class__`

```
class FooClass(object):

    def bar_method(self):
        pass

    def baz_static_method():
        pass

foo_instance = FooClass()
print(foo_instance.bar_method.__self__.__class__)
print(FooClass.baz_static_method.im_class)
```

This will get messy with multiple inheritance. Hope it helps.

Comment: If I use `func.__self__.__class__` I receive an exception: `{AttributeError}'function' object has no attribute '__self__'`

Comment: I will add an example

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Sadly, I cannot access to an instance, I have to stick to the code I posted and I can only modify my decorator function.